# How to Create key (to be used in join) using concatenation?

Tags: join

I want to inner join tables in `SQL Server 2008`, however both tables have been set without Primary Keys. How to create a key using concatenation of existing columns?

I tried the below but it only results in one record & not the entire table.

```
declare @lookup as varchar(255)  
Select  @lookup = accountID + state + product  
From Table1  
Print @lookup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand your requirements for this, however the following will return a row for each row in Table1.

Assuming [accountID] is an integer, you'd need to:

```
Select [lookup] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), accountID) + state + product
From dbo.Table1
ORDER BY accountID + state + product;
```

You should always specify the schema (I used `dbo` since it is the default).  I've also added an `ORDER BY` clause to make the output easier to understand.

It might make more sense to extend this to creation of the actual key field, as such:

```
-- add the [Lookup] column, make it nullable for now.
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD [Lookup] VARCHAR(255) NULL;
GO

-- insert the concatenated value into the [Lookup] column
UPDATE dbo.Table1
SET [Lookup] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), accountID) + state + product
FROM dbo.Table1;
GO

-- make the [Lookup] column NOT nullable so we can turn it into a primary key
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ALTER COLUMN [Lookup] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;    
GO

-- create the clustered primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Lookup]);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table1;
```

If the table `dbo.Table` already has a clustered primary key, you'd either not make `Lookup` a primary key, or perhaps you'd drop the existing primary key, and make `Lookup` the new primary key.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) concatenate a string just to join on multiple columns.

You can use

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t1
       INNER JOIN Table2 t2
               ON t1.accountID = t2.accountID
                  AND t1.state = t2.state
                  AND t1.product = t2.product;
```

Or - if the columns are nullable and you want nulls treated equal.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t1
       INNER JOIN Table2 t2
               ON EXISTS (SELECT t1.accountID,
                                 t1.state,
                                 t1.product
                          INTERSECT
                          SELECT t2.accountID,
                                 t2.state,
                                 t2.product);
```

Similarly you can create a composite PK on all three columns without this repetitious concatenated string.

(Assumes that all are `NOT NULL` and no duplicates exist)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1
  ADD CONSTRAINT YourPK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (accountID, state, product );
```